# How to select a specific record from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables asrecord of students:
[image: record of students]
record of courses:
[image: record of courses]
Map student and course:
[image: Map student and course]

I want to get records from `table std_course` where `student` are as `1,2,3` using query

```
select course_id from std_course where std_id in (1,2,3) group by course_id
```

It returns me `course_id` as `1` but here `std_id=4` also exist against `course_id=1`
I need to select `course_id` where `std_id` are only `1,2,3`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` and `select case`, `std_id` above `3` will be `0`

```
select * from (
    select sum(case when std_id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) tot
        , course_id
    from std_course
    group by course_id) t1 
where t1.tot <= 3
```

Comment: thanks @Metal its prove helpful for me but after some changes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using join:

```
select * from std_course left outer join course on course.id= std_course.course_id where std_id <=3
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that work for me after the changings in query Answered by @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ is:

```
select * from ( select sum(case when std_id in (1,2,3) then 1 else -1 end) tot , course_id from std_course group by course_id) t1 where t1.tot = 3
```